# Udacity Project Sunshine - Lesson 2 - cannot find symbol class error

Tags: android

I'm taking the Developing Android Apps udacity course and am stuck at lesson 2 of the Project Sunshine part.

seems like my code matches exactly to there's at this point (their code is here https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/compare/2.01_add_network_code...2.02_refactor_forecast_fragment) but when I run my code I encounter an error in my MainActivity.java tab that says it cannot find symbol class ForecastFragment.

Any thoughts on why this is?

My MainActivity.java code is below (error is in the onCreate method):
    package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My ForecastFragment.java code is below:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.android.sunshine.app.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

public ForecastFragment() {
}

/**
 * within this placeholder fragment is where you create the arraylist
 */

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String[] forecastArray = {
            "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
            "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
            "Weds - Cloudy - 72/63",
            "Thurs - Asteroids - 75/65",
            "Fri - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
            "Sat - HELP TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 60/51",
            "SUN - Sunny - 80/68"
    };
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

    // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
    // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
    // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
    ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                    weekForecast);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(forecastAdapter);
    return rootView;
}

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are available at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return  null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        return null;}
    }
}
```

finally (and sorry for the code overload) I have my fragment_main.xml tab:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$ForecastFragment">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Today, June 24 - 21"
    android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"
    />
```

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project? (In Android Studio, go to menu -> Build -> Clean Project)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried it but unfortunately didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just answering formally so i can close this out - I eventually solved this problem a while back. seems i forgot to delete / close the question my apologies. if i recall correctly the issue had to do with a missing import. If anyone runs into the same issue with this course I may be able to dig up the working code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your full path in fragment `_main.xml` like this:

```
tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity.ForecastFragment"
```

Comment: hey Andrei, thanks for answering. I eventually solved this problem a while back. seems i forgot to delete / close the question my apologies. if i recall correctly the issue had to do with a missing import

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, at the same point (just having refactored the "ForecastFragment" into its own files, and renamed it from "PlaceholderFragment").

The problem persisted, even with the exact same files as the ones used in the course.

I fixed it by using buiild-clean project. After doing that it built just fine.